# Colored terminal with SFTP

Tags: ftp, colors, sftp

Is there a way to get colored output in the terminal over `SFTP`? I'm thinking of colored directories, symbolic links, executables etc, the usual stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean *"SFTP"* as in *"OpenSSH `sftp` client"*: It does not support coloring the output.

If you mean *"SFTP"* as in *"SFTP protocol"*: In theory, there's nothing preventing an implementation of a command-line SFTP client that can color the output. But I do not know such client.

Comment: The `lftp` client would be my preference -- it uses LS_COLORS automatically, and allows a colourful `set cmd:prompt` as well.

Comment: I'm using the openSSH sftp (I assume, it's Ubuntu), but changing client would be fine! Thats interesting @user1686, I'll check it out, thanks!